# Javascript GooglMaps API handle does not work often

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I created web application where users will record their google co-ordinates.
For this purpose in front-end javascript I used google maps API.

Ideally the page looks like below.
[image]

I have domain and VPS server from godaddy. I also SSL certificate installed in the server.

But the issue is frequently the MAPS are not working and when the page load it gets hang. See below.
[image]

Then later i regenerate the key and restart the server, this is taking lot of time to resolve on every occurance.

Is there any way that I solve this issue permanently?
Have you come across such issues?

Google maps API as below:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
        }else{ 
            $('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
        }
    });

    function showLocation(position){    
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: baseurl+'dailyvisit/getLocation',
            data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude,
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg){
                    //alert(msg);
                    var data = msg.split('|');
                    var city = data[0].split(' - ');
                    var count = city.length;
                    $('#city').val(city[1]);
                   $("#location").val(city[0]+","+city[1]+","+city[2]);
                   $('#co_ordinates').val(data[1]+","+data[2]);
                var map;

                   var latitude = Number(data[1]); // YOUR LATITUDE VALUE
                var longitude = Number(data[2]); // YOUR LONGITUDE VALUE

                var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  center: myLatLng,
                  zoom: 14                    
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatLng,
                  map: map,
                  //title: 'Hello World'

                  // setting latitude & longitude as title of the marker
                  // title is shown when you hover over the marker
                  title: latitude + ', ' + longitude 
                });            
                }else{
                    $("#location").html('Not Available');
                }
            }
        });
    }
        function visit_validation()
        {
                var err = 0;
      var customer = $('#customerId').val();
      var contact_number = $('#contact_number').val();
      var contact_email = $('#Contact_email').val();
    /*  var name = $('#prodNameEdit').val();
      var price = $('#prodPriceEdit').val();
      var qty = $('#prodQtyEdit').val();
      var bfast = $('#breakfastEdit').val();
      var lunch = $('#lunchEdit').val();
      var dinner = $('#dinnerEdit').val();*/

      if(customer==''){
         $('#customerId_err').html('Customer name is required!');
         err++;
      }else{
         $('#customerId_err').html('');
      }
      if(contact_number.trim()==''){
            $('#cn_err').html('Contact Number is required!');
            err++;
        }else if(contact_number != parseInt(contact_number, 10)){ 
            $('#cn_err').html('Invalid Mobile Number!');
            err++;
        }else{
            $('#cn_err').html('');
        }     
             if(!ValidateEmail(contact_email) && contact_email.trim()!=''){ 
            $('#ce_err').html('Invalid Email ID!');
            err++;
        }else{
            $('#ce_err').html('');
        }       

      if(err>0){ return false; }else{ return true; }
        }
        function ValidateEmail(email){
    var expr = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return expr.test(email);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you receive any error on the console when the map doesn't load? It could be an issue while splitting to retrieve the city due to which the map creation code doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ajax call doesn't return successfully the map will not be created as the map is created only if ajax call returns success. You could move the map and marker creation code before the ajax call as follows :

```
function showLocation(position){    
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 14                    
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      //title: 'Hello World'

      // setting latitude & longitude as title of the marker
      // title is shown when you hover over the marker
      title: latitude + ', ' + longitude 
    });   

    var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: baseurl+'dailyvisit/getLocation',
        data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude,
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg){
                //alert(msg);
                var data = msg.split('|');
                var city = data[0].split(' - ');
                var count = city.length;
                $('#city').val(city[1]);
               $("#location").val(city[0]+","+city[1]+","+city[2]);
               $('#co_ordinates').val(data[1]+","+data[2]);

            }else{
                $("#location").html('Not Available');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This will create the map and marker before the ajax call. If the ajax call is successful the city, location and coordinate fields will be set, otherwise they won't be. In either case the map and marker creation will always happen and you will not have a blank map on the page.